# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred - Codable

Tags: swift, generics, codable

I have protocols with generic types. is the code below correct 
I am getting the error : "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"

[generic type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxWnF.jpg)

what am I missing?

architecture is VIPER, so I have a View, Presenter, Interactor ...

**Protocols.swift**

```
protocol OffersViewProtocol {
    var presenter: OffersPresenterProtocol? { get set }
    func setup()
    func displayResults()
}

protocol OffersPresenterProtocol {
    var interactor: OffersInteractorProtocol? { get set }
    var router: OffersRouterProtocol? { get set }
    func showResults<T: Codable>(for service: APIService,_ completion:  @escaping ResultsHandler<T>)
}

protocol OffersInteractorProtocol {
   func getResults<T: Codable>(for service: APIService,_ completion: @escaping ResultsHandler<T>)
}
```

**Interactor.swift**

```
class OffersInteractor: OffersInteractorProtocol {
    let dataManager = DataManagerService()
    func getResults<Offer>(for service: APIService, _ completion: @escaping ([Offer]?, ErrorHandler?) -> Void) {
        dataManager.get(for: service) { results in

        }
    }

}
```

**Presenter.swift**

```
class OffersPresenter: OffersPresenterProtocol {


    var interactor: OffersInteractorProtocol?

    var router: OffersRouterProtocol?

    func showResults<Offer>(for service: APIService, _ completion: @escaping ([Offer]?, ErrorHandler?) -> Void) {
        interactor?.getResults(for: service, { (results, error) in

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func showResults<Offer>(for service: APIService, _ completion: @escaping ([Offer]?, ErrorHandler?) -> Void) {
        interactor?.getResults(for: service, { (results:ResultType, error:Error) in

        })
    }
```

You should explicitly specify the type, i tried in the playground and this will work.